# How to get selected option value (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

i have form with options, when i want to add, the value is null. what i want to ask is how to get the value i've selected?

my form:

```
<select name="student_id" class="form-control" data-validate="required" id="student_id"
                      data-message-required="<?php echo get_phrase('value_required');?>"
                        onchange="return get_class_sections(this.value)">
                                    <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('Selecteaz&#259;_un_student');?></option>
                                    <?php
                      $stare='0';
                      $classes = $this->db->get_where('disertatie_studenti',array('retrasi'=>$stare))->result_array();
                      foreach($classes as $row):
                        ?>
                                      <option value="<?php echo $this->db->get_where('disertatie_studenti' , array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->row()->name;?>">
                            <?php echo $row['name'];?>
                                                  </option>
                                      <?php
                      endforeach;
                      ?>
                      </select>
```

my controller

```
$data['student_id']            = $this->input->post("student_id");
```

error message:

```
INSERT INTO `disertatie_corectura` (`student_id`, `corectura`, `timestamp`, `year`) VALUES (NULL, '2554', 1574456889, '2019-2020')
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be better to run query before `<option>` tag and then `echo` the values

Comment: Did you checked you are retrieving correct value on foreach?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<option value="<?php echo $this->db->get_where('disertatie_studenti' , array('name' => $row['name']))->row()->student_id;?>">
                                <?php echo $row['name'];?>
```

Comment: Oh my dear goodness, no.  Do not interact with your model from in your view.  You controller should ask the model to fetch database data, then the controller passes that data to the view for presentation.